# RequestTimeTooSkewed accessing S3 from lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function in node that is listing objects from an S3 bucket. The S3 bucket has versioning enabled. ListObjectsV2 is throwing a `RequestTimeTooSkewed` error. This seems to happen when the system clock is out of sync, but why would it be happening on a lambda instance?

```
RequestTimeTooSkewed: The difference between the request time and the current time is too large.\n    at throwDefaultError (/var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/node_modules/@smithy/smithy-client/dist-cjs/default-error-handler.js:8:22)\n    at /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/node_modules/@smithy/smithy-client/dist-cjs/default-error-handler.js:18:39\n    at de_ListObjectsV2CommandError (/var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/dist-cjs/protocols/Aws_restXml.js:5227:20)\n    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)\n    at async /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/node_modules/@smithy/middleware-serde/dist-cjs/deserializerMiddleware.js:7:24\n    at async /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-signing/dist-cjs/awsAuthMiddleware.js:30:20\n    at async /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/node_modules/@smithy/middleware-retry/dist-cjs/retryMiddleware.js:27:46\n    at async /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-sdk-s3/dist-cjs/region-redirect-endpoint-middleware.js:14:24\n    at async /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-sdk-s3/dist-cjs/region-redirect-middleware.js:9:20\n    at async /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-logger/dist-cjs/loggerMiddleware.js:7:26
```

Timestamp in the log seem to match the currrent time.

Appreciate any insights on this.

Comment: That's weird. How frequently does that happen?

Comment: It is definitely not on all invocations. We have them running with provisioned concurrency. Errors happen maybe 5% of the time.

Comment: Maybe something is blocking the event loop

Comment: Not sure why this would be happening, but you might try setting [correctClockSkew](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Config.html#correctClockSkew-property) to work around it.

Comment: I cant seem to find the correctClockSkew in the V3 SDK. Am I missing something?

Comment: - **v3**: **Deprecated**. SDK _always_ applies a clock skew correction.

Comment: The clock offset is adjusted in retries only if it is more than 5 mins.
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/blob/b163378b9f5f5482a95583aa569811d8cda629d9/packages/core/src/httpAuthSchemes/utils/isClockSkewed.ts#L11 

In our case the lambda time drifts on cold starts is less than a sec. That is why the adjustment is not getting applied. I was able to work around this by setting the offset myself.

Any idea why there is a threshold of over 5 mins?